# SetRowSpan not find in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to use the method setrowspan() in UWP.
It exists in UWP? 
trying:

```
 tod.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
 tod.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, i + 1);
 DayNameGrid.SetRowSpan(tod,2);
```

I get a compile error:

> CS0176  C# Member 'Grid.SetRowSpan(FrameworkElement, int)' cannot be
>   accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name
>   instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is static, you're trying to call it like an instance method.

```
Grid.SetRowSpan(tod, 2);
```

Don't worry, it'll automatically apply to the element's parent grid (simply put).

Note that you can use the same syntax for the other properties, if you like:

```
Grid.SetRow(tod, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(tod, i + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is telling you that the method is a static method, so you should call it as auch.

'`Grid.SetRowSpan(tod,2);`'